# ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException error at downloading file from server on webview Android

Tags: android, jsp

This is my downloading code. It works on browser but not works on webview it gets ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException exception.
Is there another way to download file from server on webview Android.

```
    public static void downloadFile(String filePath,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = response.getOutputStream();

        File file = new File(filePath);
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
                + file.getName());
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[1024];
        // copy binary contect to output stream
        while (true) {
            int read = in.read(outputByte, 0, 1024);
            if (read == -1)
                break;
            os.write(outputByte, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```